# Sort Order With End Year and Start Year

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, comparator

I'm looking to write a `comparator` to sort my items in a list.

For items without an end year they should be at the top.

For items with an end year they should be next.

For items with the same end year the one with the lowest start year should be next.

Something I have so far

`[item.get('end_year'), item.get('start_year')]`

Test sceanrios first is end year second is start year ("" is present)

```
"", ""
"", 2012
"", 2011
2012, 2005
2012, 2008
2011, 2011
2010, 2005
```

Comment: Can you paste a small example of sample data sorted the way you want it? Kind of hard to tell exactly what you're asking for from the description.

Comment: I'm pretty sure mysql handles this as `end_date asc, start_date desc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a comaprator function to your collection that takes two models in a 'sort' function. This will maintain your collection in sorted order as models are added to it. Note that if you change the start_year or end_year of a single model, you will have to resort the collection manually.

```
comparator: function(item1,item2) {
  var y1 = {
    start: item1.get('start_year'),
    end: item1.get('end_year')
  },
  y2 = {
    start: item2.get('start_year'),
    end: item2.get('end_year')
  };

  // If one item has no end year, sort it first
  if(y1.end === '' && y2.end !== '') return -1;
  if(y1.end !== '' && y2.end === '') return 1;

  // Sort the higher end year first
  if(y1.end > y2.end) return -1;
  if(y1.end < y2.end) return 1;

  // Sort the lower start year first
  if(y1.start < y2.start) return -1;
  if(y1.start > y2.start) return 1;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yup! Should be noted this depends on backbone 0.9.3 or rather underscore's sortBy.

Comment: @mu is too short, curious as to what you edited; I don't see any differences. was it a typo?

Comment: You had a stray `}` above the `return 0`, it was clearly just a typo so I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

With truthiness and coffescript:

```
comparator: (a, b) ->
    return -1 if not a.get("end_year") and b.get("end_year")
    return 1  if a.get("end_year") and not b.get("end_year")
    return -1 if a.get("end_year") > b.get("end_year")
    return 1  if a.get("end_year") < b.get("end_year")
    return -1 if a.get("start_year") < b.get("start_year")
    return 1  if a.get("start_year") > b.get("start_year")

    0
```

Comment: You should have said you wanted coffeescript; I could have saved myself a few keystrokes :)